# Applying a global coordinate translation to an Obj file

Tags: object, geospatial, coordinate-transformation, .obj, photogrammetry

I currently use photogrammetry software and GCP’s to turn drone photos into a georeferenced obj file which I then import to a second software. I have had to switch to a new photogrammetry software which exports the obj and the offset coordinates as two separate files. Is there a way to include the offset coordinates back into the obj file to make it georeferenced before it’s imported to the next stage of processing? For reference, I previously used agisoft metashape but am now trying to find a way to use Pix4D with my existing software.

I’ve tried opening the obj in excel, via notepad, and applying the offset to each individual vertices, and then pasting it back into the original obj file but I get an error. I need to keep the process simple as possible as I’ll be creating 2-3 models a day. Thankful for any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide any example of the data that you have: some rows from OBJ file with the coordinate data and the offset file that you have? Does it include the information about the coordinate system?

I think adding XYZ offsets to the corresponding coordinate values in the OBJ file would work, if projected coordinate system is used, where all units are in meters. But if the reference coordinate system is WGS84 (with Latitude/Longitude values in meters) you will need to apply additional conversion, for example, convert the offset point from WGS84 to geocentric coordinates - add this offset to the coordinates of the points in the OBJ file and finally convert them from geocentric to WGS84.